# (REACT) How to disable picked options for all Select fields ? I want to disable option for all Selects if it is picked in any Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have my Select and Form component. Basically i try to do the functionality that when i select one option in any Select, this option should be disabled for other Select components as long as it's selected. For example you pick "Option 1" in first select, and as long as it's picked it's disabled for other Selects. I tried plenty solutions for few hours but nothing worked

```
import React from "react";
import "./Select.scss";

const Select = (props) => {
  return (
    <select
      className="driverselect"
      onChange={props.onChange}
    >
      <option value="">Select an option</option>
      {props.options}
    </select>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

I use it in my Form.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "./Select";

import "./Form.scss";

const Form = () => {
  //const [isAlreadySelected, setIsAlreadySelected] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: "option1", label: "Option 1", disabled: null },
    { id: 2, value: "option2", label: "Option 2", disabled: null },
    { id: 3, value: "option3", label: "Option 3", disabled: null },
    { id: 4, value: "option4", label: "Option 4", disabled: null },
    { id: 5, value: "option5", label: "Option 5", disabled: null },
    { id: 6, value: "option6", label: "Option 6", disabled: null },
    { id: 7, value: "option7", label: "Option 7", disabled: null },
    { id: 8, value: "option8", label: "Option 8", disabled: null },
  ]);

  const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.value;

    setOptions((prevOptions) => {
      return prevOptions.map((option) => {
        if (option.value === selectedOption) {
          return { ...option, disabled: true };
        } else {
            return { ...option, disabled: false };
        }
      });
    });
    console.log("VALUE CHANGED. SELECTED OPTION: ", event.target.value);
  };

  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => (
    <option key={option.id} value={option.value} disabled={option.disabled}>
      {option.label}
    </option>
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <form className="bet">
        <Select
          name="select1"
          options={renderedOptions}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
        <Select
          name="select2"
          options={renderedOptions}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
        <Select
          name="select3"
          options={renderedOptions}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
        <Select
          name="select4"
          options={renderedOptions}
          onChange={handleSelectChange}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I tried something with useEffect, i tried with more state variables, i tried with 4 useState for 4 selects that i use but i was probably doing it wrong